# weblogic server is goes in warning state

Tags: weblogic12c, bridge

I am connecting 2 different application using `web-logic jms bridge`.

But when I check for bridge its showing in warning state and error is fail to connect target. and after some time server is go in warning state.

Can anyone help me in this?

> Exception [JMSException045028] the message threshold  for jms server
>   ***** has been exceeded more than one hour.

using weblogic 12c

Comment: did you check that messages are consumed ?

Comment: I am using different nodes. So this all massage s are consuming slowly as bridge is going in active and again going inactive state which pile up massage on sever and it makes my server in Warning state.